# C++ templates in GCC

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc

I have problems with porting Windows application to Linux (GCC).

I have the following code in Windows (Visual Studio 2010 compiling it well):
I have template class, that contains a structure.

```
    template<typename bidtype>
    class pst_bc_block : public pst_entries_block<bidtype>
    {
public:
    ...
    struct tag_bc
        {
            WORD  ID;
            WORD  type;
            DWORD  value;
        };
    ...
    }
```

When I'm trying to do something like this:

```
pst_bc_block<bidtype>::tag_bc tag_value;
tag_value.ID = 6;
```

GCC can't resolve ID member.

P.S. All windows types are defined and VS comple it well.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Field 'ID' could not be resolved  Semantic Error

Comment: Please consider adding the exact error message in the question to improve it. Without an exact copy of the whole message it could be hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: The minimal expansion of your code seems to compile and run fine in gcc: http://ideone.com/mREgig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tag_bc is a *template-dependent type*. Try this :

```
typename pst_bc_block<bidtype>::tag_bc tag_value;
```

Edit: you will probably encounter trouble if you forgot to redefine Windows' WORD, DWORD and such.

Comment: You could consider improving your answer by extending the explanation for both the typename and the WORD ;)

Comment: I'm not much of a good teacher to be honest, so I'm used to leaving clear keywords for further research instead of trying and patching together an explanation... As for WORD, I just know that it's some Windowsian type, no more. uint32 ?

Comment: WORD is unsigned short